# Why does ObjectAnimator setDuration not work?

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I'm trying to move a `RelativeLayout` to the left inside my `Fragment` using `ObjectAnimator`.

The method `setDuration` doesn't change the duration at all.

I'm not looking for `setStartDelay()` method

**The position is being changed instantaneously**:

```
RelativeLayout layoutConfig2 = (RelativeLayout) rootView1.findViewById(R.id.layoutListConfig2);
ObjectAnimator pullLeft = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layoutConfig2, "translationX", 0f, -600f);
pullLeft.setDuration(4000); // ?
pullLeft.start();
```

Here is my full `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.params_config, container, false);

        ListView listConfiguracoes = (ListView) rootView1.findViewById(R.id.list1_configParameters);
        ListView listMotor = (ListView) rootView1.findViewById(R.id.list_motor1);
        final RelativeLayout layoutConfig1 = (RelativeLayout) rootView1.findViewById(R.id.layoutListConfig);
        final RelativeLayout layoutConfig2 = (RelativeLayout) rootView1.findViewById(R.id.layoutListConfig2);

        menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array1_config);
        menuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.arrow_icons);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < menutitles.length; i++) {
            RowItem items = new RowItem(menutitles[i], menuIcons.getResourceId(
                    i, -1));
            rowItems.add(items);
        }


        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems, 2);
        listConfiguracoes.setAdapter(adapter);
        listMotor.setAdapter(adapter);
        layoutConfig2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        listConfiguracoes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Animation slide1, slide2;
                slide1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.move_left_slightly);
                slide2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.move_left_fast);


                switch (position) {
                    case 0:

                        layoutConfig1.startAnimation(slide1);

                        ObjectAnimator pullLeft = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layoutConfig2, "translationX", 0f, -600f);
                        pullLeft.setDuration(4000); // ?
                        pullLeft.start();

                        break;
                }
            }
        });


        return rootView1;

    }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do other animations work on your test device?

Comment: Yes they do. I was using `slide1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.move_left_slightly);` before, but it doesn't move the clickable contents.

Comment: Where do you call this code?

Comment: This is declared on a Fragment's `ListView onItemClick`, inside the `onCreateView` method.

Comment: Post the full `onCreateView` method.

Comment: @Machado you absolutely sure `pullLeft.start()` is even called? And layout in question (`layoutConfig2`) is visible?

Comment: Yes. It is called because it becomes visible and changes the position, but not like an sliding animation. The setDuration method should add this effect, am I wrong?

Comment: This doesn't seem like an obvious problem. You need to do some debugging yourself. For example comment out the `ObjectAnimator` block completely and see if anything changes. The best thing would be to try to re-create the problem with as little code as possible, preferably on a new project.

Comment: Do you guys even read the post? The OP wants to change the duration of the animation, however the animation gets executed instantly.

Answer (score 2):

Cant say why its not working, but heres a good alternative. Use `ViewPropertyAnimator` :

```
layoutConfig2.animate().translationX(-600).setDuration(4000);
```

`ViewPropertyAnimator` can make your life easier ;).

Comment: Just added in the code. Although I like this alternative, the position is being changed instantaneously too.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit late, but in case anyone run into this thread:
Try the "Animator duration scale" under Developer Options. I had this problem when mine was disabled.